# Await array is not empy, but has length = 0

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, async-await

Currently trying to write a react app where I use data from an api. I have an async componentDidMount attempting to set the state with the awaited array, returned from getGameData()

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const data = await getGameData()
  this.setState({
    games: await data
  });
}
```

However, when I log the state value of the state array, "data" along with its length it returns 0 for length, but the data is visible in the array (See picture). I believe this is what is causing further problems preventing me from mapping the array. Thanks in advance for any help resolving this issue.

Note: Have tried with and without await before data, the problem persists.

[The attached shows the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtywH.png)

Comment: remove await  in games: await data

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried with and without await before data in setState @Nonik The problem stays

Comment: _"when I log the state value"_... the key part of this statement is **when**. When you log the length, have you waited for the data to finish loading?

Comment: @Phil both are being logged at rendering stage, note the length is logged after the array itself.

Comment: How can I _"note"_ anything if you haven't shown that code?